# docker-compose expose on a random port when no variable is set in env

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want docker-compose to:

- Expose on the port in `.env` file
- And expose on a random if it's not set in the `.env` file

I've tried this but it always exposes a random port.

```
ports:
      - 80
```

I've tried this but it always exposes on 80 when there is no value in env.

```
ports:
      - ${PORT:-80}
```

What I like to achieve could be something like this:

```
ports:
      - ${PORT:-RANDOM}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the default to 0 will cause the operating system to assign a random port.

For example:

```
ports:
      - ${APP_PORT:-0}:80
```